# Deflate algorithm in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, compression, deflate

I need to make a Deflate code in Matlab. I understood how to make a file, comressed by matlab with matlab.io.hdf4.sd.getcompinfo and H5P.set_deflate(plist_id,level), but I guess that its not what exactly I want.

I need to compress bitstream of the image by Deflate and by my algorithm and compare output bitstreams. Maybe I just don't understand how to do it by standart functions? I need assistance anyway.

Comment: Any reason you can't just link to the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) callable function? Seems a whole lot easier than writing your own deflate compressor. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop for info on linking to external code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [gzip already built in to MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gzip.html). If you really want just the deflate payload in the gzip file, then you can strip the gzip header and trailer.

Your need to "compare output bitstreams" is odd. What are you looking for? Note that there can be many deflate compressions of the same input data that are all valid.